# Keep on getting wrong value for linear regression $\beta$ estimator derivation

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider the simple regression model through the origin
$$Y=\beta x + R$$where $R\sim G(0,\sigma)$.

Find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\beta$.

I keep getting $$\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}$$
which I know is wrong...could anybody point me in the correct direction? Maybe I'm just relying on wolfram too much, but some steps, for example, converting the likelihood function to log likelihood, seem insanely messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would this be wrong? This is exactly the OLS estimator, and ML produces the same coefficients. For a detailed derivation with multiple regression, see [here](http://users.polisci.wisc.edu/franklin/Content/MLE/Lecs/MLELec05p4up.pdf) or [here](http://www.xycoon.com/mle.htm).